Contourf colourbar ticklabels are wrongly formatted with matplotlib 3.5.1 (python3)
I am trying to do contour plotting with the log scale for some data. And I seem to have run into an issue that I cannot find a solution for.
When I use contourf plot and plot the colourbar in the log scale, the ticklabels on the colorbar are formatted to %.4f as seen below for the example code.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

# Create sample data
x = np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, 100)
y = np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)

# Create a contour plot with logarithmic color normalization
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
contour = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=50, norm=mcolors.LogNorm())

# Add color bar with logarithmic scale
cbar = fig.colorbar(contour, ax=ax)
cbar.set_label('Log scale color bar')

plt.show()


This is unlike the default example on matplotlibs website that shows that the colourbar should be shown with powers of 10 as labels. See the example for how it should actually appear. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am using Linux mint 21.3, matplotlib: 3.5.1.

I have already tried the following additional code and it does not seem to change anything other than just making the ticklabels in %.2f format.
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
cbar.locator = mticker.LogLocator(base=10.0)
cbar.update_ticks()


This is a bug that was fixed at Matplotlib v3.6.3.  You should upgrade your Matplotlib version.  https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/23389

Agree with @RuthC, but if upgrading is not possible on your system, then adding cbar.ax.set_yscale('log') at the end of your script should fix things

Thanks both RuthC and @tmdavison. Since I do not want to update my system python3 at this point, I will use the workaround. And it seems to work well.
